# Java For Loop not ending with Sentinel

Tags: java

I am creating a program that takes in employee payroll information and then displays the average and total afterwards. Everything seems to be working correctly except for the fact I cannot get the program to end when I enter the sentinel value of -1 for the hours worked so that the program can display the total and average of the employees. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PayrollDo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        int hoursWorked = 0;
        int grossPay = 0;
        int empCounter = 0;
        int total = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

do { 
                    total = total + grossPay; // add gross to total
                    empCounter = empCounter + 1; // incriment counter

                    System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
                    hoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();  

                    System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: ");
                    int hourlyWage = keyboard.nextInt();

                    //System.out.println("Grosspay is " + (hourlyWage * hoursWorked));
                    keyboard.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter employee name ");
                    String name = keyboard.nextLine();


} while(hoursWorked != -1);




        // if user entered at least one employee
        if (empCounter != 0) {
            // use number with decimal point to calculate average of employees
            int average = (int) total / empCounter;

            // display total and average (with two digits of precision)
            System.out.printf("%nTotal of the %d employees entered is %d%n", 
                empCounter, total);
            System.out.printf("Employee average is " + average);
        } 
        else { 
            // no employees were entered, so output appropriate message 
            System.out.println("No employees were entered");
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: What behavior is leading you to conclude that the sentinel isn't working?  Does the "Enter hours worked:" prompt eventually reappear?

Answer (score 0):

Test soon after entering the value whether it is `-1` or not

```
System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
hoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();  
if (hoursWorked == -1) break;
```

**edit**
I think you will also have trouble with Integer division http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your do loop to put the hoursWorked input last (otherwise you have to complete the entries) - and also, add a conditional to reject all entries that cycle, otherwise empCounter is off by one. And I think the total calculation needs reworking too:

```
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter employee name ");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: ");
            int hourlyWage = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
            hoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();  

            keyboard.nextLine();
            if (hoursWorked != -1) {
                total = total + (hourlyWage * hoursWorked); // 
                empCounter = empCounter + 1; // incriment counter
            }
        } while(hoursWorked != -1);
```

In cases like this it can be simpler to have a question like "More Employees? (y/n)" that is used to terminate the loop, using a boolean flag as the while terminator.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!